# How to interpret geeglm results?

Tags: biostatistics, generalized-estimating-equations

I have a question about the `geeglm` function in the GEE package in R. I am a beginner in statistics and the estimates in the output of the model are puzzling me. How can I tell that the estimates are ok and how can I recognise overdispersion?

- The output looks like this:

  ```
  Call: geeglm(formula = logSUM ~ teplota + radiace.rezidualy + srazky2, 
  family = gaussian, data = PH1, id = den, corstr = "ar1") 

  Coefficients: Estimate Std.err Wald Pr(>|W|) 

  (Intercept) -0.933429 0.515005 3.29 0.070 . 

  teplota 0.163241 0.028613 32.55 1.2e-08 *** 

  radiace.rezidualy -0.000842 0.000397 4.50 0.034 * 

  srazky2 -0.153942 0.037414 16.93 3.9e-05 *** 

  --- Signif. codes: 0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

  Estimated Scale Parameters:

           Estimate Std.err
  (Intercept)    0.8  0.08

  Correlation: Structure = ar1  Link = identity

  Estimated Correlation Parameters:

     Estimate Std.err
   alpha    0.7  0.05

   Number of clusters:   24   Maximum cluster size: 16
  ```

Thank you for any feedback or suggestions.

Comment: Where is the output for the coefficients? Also, why are you using a generalized estimating equation ?

Comment: Overdispersion is generally a term used when a Poisson distribution is used. It means the variance is larger than the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please post the entire code for your model. Without seeing the code, I would say that you might have log coefficients. This is entirely dependent on the link function, however. If you do have log coefficients, in order to get a coefficient that is easy to understand you must exponentiate the estimate: exp(Beta). This will give you a rate ratio. Numbers over 1, for instance 1.1, would mean a 10 % increase in the response variable. Numbers less than 1, for  instance .9, would be a decrease. These numbers are related. Divide 1 by 1.1 and you will get .9 and if you divide .9 by 1 you will get 1.1. See here for more information (https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/180).

Comment: The entire output looks like this: 
Call:
geeglm(formula = logSUM ~ teplota + radiace.rezidualy + srazky2, 
    family = gaussian, data = PH1, id = den, corstr = "ar1")

 Coefficients:
                   Estimate   Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)       -0.933429  0.515005  3.29    0.070 .  
teplota            0.163241  0.028613 32.55  1.2e-08 ***
radiace.rezidualy -0.000842  0.000397  4.50    0.034 *  
srazky2           -0.153942  0.037414 16.93  3.9e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Comment: Estimated Scale Parameters:
            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)    0.722  0.0749

Correlation: Structure = ar1  Link = identity 

Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate Std.err
alpha    0.605  0.0523
Number of clusters:   24   Maximum cluster size: 16
I have been adviced to use this kind of model but I am really unexperianced in Mixed effect models. And I was not able to find any explanation on the estimated parameters If there is or there is not over dispersion and I can use this model.
Thank you

Comment: @Misha: Please edit the question to include this info. - it'll get missed down here in comments (as well as being horribly formatted).

Answer (score 0):

Since your outcome variable is logSum, you have to exponentiate the coefficients.
This is very easy to do in R. For teplota, the exponentiated coefficient would be 1.17732. In r, the code is very straight forward:

```
exp(.163241)
```

This means that, for a one unit increase in teplota, there would be a 17 % increase in the outcome variable (see here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/log_transformed_regression.htm.)

The clusters are simply the groups of the id variable, in this case den. You have 24 levels of den and the largest group is 16. As for the correlation structure, autogressive AR(1) is generally used for time series data. This is because time points are often correlated with one another. You may not need this. In order to check for autocorrelation, you need to generate an acf plot. I am not sure how to do this using geeglm, so I will use lme4 with the lmer function.

```
install.packages("lme4")
install.packages("itsadug")
require(lme4)
require(itsadug)
den <- factor(PH1$den)

m1 <- lmer(logSum ~ teplota + radiace.rezidualy + srazky2 + (1|den), data = PH1)
summary(m1) ## check coefficients

acf_resid(m1, main = "ACF Plot") ## if any vertical lines are above the horizontal blue dotted line you have autocorrelation.
```

If you have autocorrelation, as indicated by the acf plot, you can proceed with your original model. You could explore other packages, for instance, nlme or lme4. I would recommend lme4, but you will have to do a little work to get p-values that you are comfortable with. In the package description, you will have to browse the table of contents for pvalues.

```
car::Anova(m1) ## for p-values
```

If you do not have autocorrelation, my model using lme4 would be appropriate.

If this answered your question, please mark your post as answered. If this does not answer your original question, please describe your situation in more detail.

Comment: thank you, I checked the autocorrelation the way you described and it is neccessary for the model. thanks to your comment I understand the output little better. Now I am fighting how to valide the model since I need to use the autocorrelation structure.

Comment: @misha. If possible, can you post a picture of the acf plot